# How to make querySelectorAll select only from child elements of the current element

Tags: javascript, css, selectors-api

What I'm asking is how to implement the equivalent functionality of jQuery's children() with HTML5's querySelector/querySelectorAll, i.e. how do I designate the current element in the selector pattern.

For example:

```
  <div id="foo">
    <div class="bar" id="div1">
      <div class="bar" id="div1.1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar" id="div2"></div>
  </div>
```

With `document.getElementById('foo').querySelectAll('div.bar')` all three `div`s will be selected. What if I only wanna get div1 and div2, not div1's child div1.1? How do I write `[[current node]] > div.bar` like css selector?

Could anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: If you log or alert the innerHTML of the foo element, you will see that the browser is rendering your content differently than the literal source code. The p elements are closed and separated instead of containing inner- p elements.

Comment: Get it! p is not supposed to be nested in p.;)

Answer (score 6):

In your example you have `did id="foo"`, so above example works.

But in a situation when parent element has no ID, but you still want to use querySelectorAll to get immediate children - it is also possible to use `:scope` to reference element like this:

```
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1'); //get child
    var pdiv = div1.parentNode; //get parent wrapper
    var list = pdiv.querySelectorAll(':scope > div.bar');
```

Here query will be "rooted" to pdiv element..

Comment: That's way too bleeding edge to be useful, at the moment (and it was proposed last year!).
`:scope` is available in Chrome or Firefox after enabling a configuration flag, and not available in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a *pseudo-class* `:scope` to select the current element, however, it is **not** designated as being supported by any version of *MS Internet Explorer*.

```
document.getElementById('foo').querySelectAll(':scope>div.bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no selector for designating the element from which the `.querySelectorAll` was called *(though I think something may have been proposed)*.

So you *can't* do anything like this:

```
var result = document.getElementById('foo').querySelectorAll('[[context]] > p.bar');
```

---

What you'd need would be to select from the document, and include the `#foo` ID in the selector.

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll("#foo > p.bar");
```

---

But if you must start with an element, one possibility would be to take its ID (assuming it has one) and concatenate it into the selector.

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll("#" + elem.id + " > p.bar");
```

---

If it's possible that the element doesn't have an ID, then you could temporarily give it one.

```
var origId = elem.id

if (!origId) {
    do {
        var id = "_" + Math.random().toString(16)
    } while (document.getElementById(id));

    elem.id = id;
}

var result = document.querySelectorAll("#" + elem.id + " > p.bar");

elem.id = origId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#foo > p.bar')
```

Comment: But what I need to do is to pass element E to a function, and let the function select something from E's children, not descendants